# Active Directory Web-based Front-End

Tags: windows, active-directory, web-applications

I'm in search for a nice web front end to a medium sized active directory. The main use case is to automate tasks that can't be done with copy from templates (things like assigning proper UNIX attributes for IDMU, creating contacts for email forwards, etc.) and to be able to create certain simple interfaces - ie stuff that one could give HR to work with or certain special uses where user data is kept in AD and needs to be modified frequently by less privileged people for their custom apps that use AD as a credentials data base. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

I'd be very interesting in hearing other people's suggestions because we're currently considering purchasing [AD Manager Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/). It has templates for user creation, seems to work well with delegating, etc. Whether its suitable for your needs - I guess you'll have to test it.

Comment: I've tinkered with AD Manager Plus. I like the functionallity, although I'm not a fan of web GUI's as they tend to be slower than a traditional GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using AD Manager Plus for about two years now and have been very pleased with it.  They allow you to very specifically control what a user is and is not allowed to do.  I haven't messed around with the templates, but I'll try that out today and report back.  The main reason we got it was to delegate user password changes and unlocks to helpdesk techs with no AD rights.  There are great reporting tools as well as bulk modification tools that can utilize .csv  files.  They are constantly adding new features and upgrading versions is a simple process.

Update:

The User Creation/ Modification template is very clean and organized.  You can also create custom templates which can utilize custom AD attributes you define.

Comment: can you define a "workflow" like creating user and putting it into a specific OU and groups but also create a exchange contact and define email forward address and say then generate a PDF that can be sent to a user that contains what his account setup is? (groups, email fwd or not, creation date, expiry, etc.)

Comment: You have the ability to select what OU the user is created in on the template.  There are options to create exchange contacts, however, i have not tried this feature.  You also can run a custom script after successful creation.